# Tests with smartctl vs smartd

Tags: raid, software-raid, smart, smartctl

I am looking into setting up smartmontools.

I'd like to control when the tests run. I was thinking of running:

`/usr/sbin/smartctl --test=short /dev/sdX`  (every week)
`/usr/sbin/smartctl --test=long /dev/sdX`   (every month)

And send an email/alert if an error is found.

1) Am I right to say that if I have the above set up in a cron, I don't need to have "smartd" daemon running in background?

2) Is there any advantage in enabling Offline Data Collection, if I run the tests above and have "smartd" disabled?

3) And the last thing that's been bugging me is that I see in the [documentation](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in) that the commands for enabling/disabling --smart, --offlineauto and --saveauto are listed as Obsolete in ATA specifications. Does this mean that all these features are obsolete/useless on ATA devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `smartd` works quite well, I would not rely on custom scripts. But let reply to each question:

- *Q: Am I right to say that if I have the above set up in a cron, I don't need to have "smartd" daemon running in background?* **R:** While technically correct, you have to *discover* the presence of an error: `smartctl`, by itself, immediately return with exit code 0. You then had to parse the output of `smartctl --all` and examine the exit status of the previos test run;
- *Q: Is there any advantage in enabling Offline Data Collection, if I run the tests above and have "smartd" disabled?* **R:** Probably not. However, Offline Data Collection by itself will not cause any (noticeable) performance hit.
- *Q: And the last thing that's been bugging me is that I see in the documentation that the commands for enabling/disabling --smart, --offlineauto and --saveauto are listed as Obsolete in ATA specifications. Does this mean that all these features are obsolete/useless on ATA devices?* **R:** while marked as "obsolete", each single HDD I have supports them. That said, each disk seems to implement them in a different (and inconsitent) manner, especially regarding SMART attributes update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Regarding Offline Data Collection, I was based on documentation saying "This type of test can, in principle, degrade the device performance.".

Comment: *In principle* this is true, but any modern disk runs offline tests with no noticeable performance impact (at least in my experience).